# why a[:,[x]] could create a column vector from an array?

Tags: python, numpy, pytorch, tensor

why a[:,[x]] could create a column vector from an array? The [ ] represents what?
Could anyone explain to me the principle?

```
a = np.random.randn(5,6)
a = a.astype(np.float32)
print(a)
c = torch.from_numpy(a[:,[1]])
```

```
[[-1.6919796   0.3160475   0.7606999   0.16881375  1.325092    0.71536326]
 [ 1.217861    0.35804042  0.0285245   0.7097111  -2.1760604   0.992101  ]
 [-1.6351479   0.6607222   0.9375339   0.5308735  -1.9699149  -2.002803  ]
 [-1.1895325   1.1744579  -0.5980689  -0.8906375  -0.00494479  0.51751447]
 [-1.7642071   0.4681248   1.3938268  -0.7519176   0.5987852  -0.5138923 ]]
###########################################
tensor([[0.3160],
        [0.3580],
        [0.6607],
        [1.1745],
        [0.4681]])
```

Comment: See [advanced indexing](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/arrays.indexing.html#advanced-indexing). You're using a sequence object (in this case the list `[1]`) which makes advanced indexing rules apply.

Comment: `[1]` is a  list with 1 element!  Don't skip basic Python learning.  You start with a (5,6), and get a (5,1) array, where the `1` is the length of the indexing list.

Answer (score 0):

The [ ] mean you are giving extra dimension. Try numpy shape method to see the diference.

```
a[:,1].shape
```

output :

```
(10,)
```

with [ ]

```
a[:,[1]].shape
```

output :

```
(10,1)
```

Answer (score 0):

That syntax is for array slicing in numpy, where arrays are indexed as `a[rows, columns, page, ... (higher-dimensions)]`

Selecting for a specific row/column/page is done by giving a specific number or range of numbers. So when you use `a[1,2]`, numpy gets the element from row 1, column 2.

You can select for several specific indices by giving the dimension multiple values. So `a[[1,3],1]` gets you both elements (1,1) and (1,3).

The `:` tells numpy to get everything from that specific array dimension. So when you use `a[:,1]`, numpy gets every row in column 1. Alternatively, `a[1,:]` gets every column in row 1.